# bluestacks cant get firebase token showing "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed an app that uses Firebase cloud messaging services 
when I run the app on android studio emulator API 25 it works normally and gets the registration token but when I debug it on bluestacks app player API 19
-that has Google services installed -
 bluestacks shows me an error "FirebaseInstanceId:backgroundsyncfailed:PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR

gradle app file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'}
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dania.Test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "2.2"
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the manifest file where services are declared

```
 <service android:name=".FireBaseService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".FCMTokenRefreshListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FCMRegistrationService" />
```

Comment: Is the Google Play services up-to-date?

Comment: it has Google Play services version  12  the last update I've made was since a month @AL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the blue stack itself and Google services
I delete blue stacks app player and remove all applications from it then I reinstall it again after that  I update google service to version 13.2.87 I install my application
 it starts getting tokens normally  without problems